# How to map from one coordinate/rotation system to another?

Tags: quaternions

I'm using an Augmented Reality SDK to define a polygon in 3d space. What the SDK gives me back is a list of [poses](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Pose) (3 translation coordinates, and a rotation quaternion), say `P0`, `P1`, `P2`, `P3`. Each one with a different translation and rotation.

I can save just one of them. Say `P0`. (the why is irrelevant to my question).

For a different user, the sdk can resolve the saved `P0`, but with different translation/quaternions because the world origin would be different. Let's call it `P0'`

I'm struggling to understand how to go about inferring the whole polygon out `P0`, `P1`, `P2`, `P3` **AND** `P0'`. In other words, I want to calculate the values of `P1'`, `P2'` and `P3'`.

I am sorry if the question is naive. I don't even know what keywords to use to Google for hints.

Comment: There are many questions left out from your post: 1. How is the polygon related to the poses? If you specify the vertices, you don't need any rotation. 2. Do you know the polygon shape? For example, it's always a square of side 1. 3. Is the second user coordinate system just translated, or is it rotated as well?

Comment: Fair. 1. I think I need the rotations because when I get back P0' it has a transalation and rotation that is from the perspective of another person's position. 2. Not in advance, but I know P0, P1, P2, P3 etc, so I can infer the shape of the polygon. In most cases it's a rectangle, but drawn by a human so it does not have perfect angles and I don't know its dimension in advance either.